# If $x_n(t)\to x(t)$ uniformly on $[0,1]$ ($x_n(t), \ x(t)\in \mathbb{R}^n)$, then $\int_0^1 \|\dot{x}_m(t)-\dot{x}(t) \|dt \to 0$.

Tags: lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples, uniform-convergence

Is this statement true? If no, could you please give me a counterexample?

If $x_n(t)\to x(t)$ uniformly on $[0,1]$ ($x_n(t), \ x(t)\in \mathbb{R}^n)$, then $\int_0^1 \|\dot{x}_m(t)-\dot{x}(t) \|dt \to 0$.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not true.
Consider, for example, the sequence $x_n(t) := \frac{\sin(2\pi nt)}{n}$.
Then $(x_n)$ converges uniformly in $\mathbb{R}$ to $x(t) \equiv 0$, but 
$$
\int_0^1 |\dot{x}_n(t)-\dot{x}(t)|\, dt = 2\pi \int_0^1 |\cos(2\pi nt)|\, dt = \int_0^{2\pi} |\cos y|\, dy
$$ 
does not converge to $0$.

Comment: Thank you @Rigel. I have one more question, if $x_n \to x$ strongly in $W^{1,2}([0,1];\mathbb{R}^n)$ (sobolev space) then the statement becomes true, is it right?

Comment: Yes, because in this case you have $\|\dot{x}_n-\dot{x}\|_2 \to 0$ and, since $[0,1]$ has finite measure, also $\|\dot{x}_n-\dot{x}\|_1 \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks so much @Rigel